# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u201c' in position 37: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python

i am just reading some quotes from file and sending them on my email using python but i am constantly facing this (**UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u201c' in position 37: ordinal not in range(128)**) error how can i fix it.

Here is the code

```
now = dt.datetime.now()
weekdays = now.weekday()

if weekdays == 5:
    with open("quotes.txt","r", encoding="utf8") as quote_file:
        all_quotes = quote_file.readlines()
        quote = random.choice(all_quotes)

    print(quote)

    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.mail.yahoo.com") as connection:
        connection.starttls()
        connection.login(user=my_email, password=my_password)
        connection.sendmail(from_addr=my_email,
                            to_addrs=my_email,
                            msg=f"Subject:Monday Motivational Quote\n\n{quote}")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: msg=f"Subject:Monday Motivational Quote\n\n{quote}".encode("utf8")
use .encode() method in the last line

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're doing Angela Yu's course. The only way I was able to get this code to work is when I removed the `""` and special characters from the `"quotes.txt"` file.

You can try it out by just removing it from the first sentence (or line), and then assign `"quote"` to `all_quotes[0]`. So this part of the code will look like this:

```
with open("quotes.txt") as quote_file:
    all_quotes = quote_file.readlines()
    quote = all_quotes[0]
```

Once you remove the special characters from every sentence, it will work with the `random.choice` too.